# Update locked by select

Tags: sql, postgresql

On my webapp, some queries run 3 min (I know, it's huge ...).
In the same time another user try to update data from the same table.
It seems that update query wait end of select for running.

Is it standard operating way for PostgreSQL ? Is there a way for forcing update for executing before the end of select query ?

Thanks.

Comment: That's strange, by default a PostgreSQL `select` should not block an `update`, see [MVVC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/mvcc-intro.html)  Are there explicit locking hints in the `select` query?

Comment: Did you include an `for update` clause in your `select`? Or did you do an explicit exclusive table lock before running the `update`?

Comment: Is that SELECT part of a transaction, and if yes, what are the other queries involved?

Comment: Thank you for your answers/questions. I will check if MVCC isn't disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable MVCC so this is not the issue.  MVCC referrs to the way rows are stored on disk and low locking is avoided.

You should understand MVCC when trying to understand how and when PostgreSQL locking may be necessary.  Normally readers do not block readers or writers.  And rarely do writers block readers.

Readers and writers can usually avoid blocking eachother by working off of snapshots which are reasonably stable through the life of the statement or transaction (the exact stability depends on the transaction level).

Row locking is still possible but it must be explicitly asked for.  `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` will lock rows selected for.  So the first thing to do is to check and see if `SELECT` statements have a `for update` predicate.

If that is not the case, then check isolation levels and try running under the `read committed` isolation level

Beyond that check the pg_locks table and see what is actually being locked.